# How to dynamically insert html content into an existing html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Say, I have an html document named *index.html*.
Also, I have another html document named *blog_content.html*.

What I want is when the clients request for *index.html*, a dynamic number of *blog_content.html*s could be loaded into *index.html*. Moreover, the contents in *blog_content.html* are also dynamically generated.

And *blog_content.html* may look like:

```
<div class="a_blog_container" id="${article.id}">
<h2>${article.title}</h2>
<h3>${article.metadata.date}</h3>
<div class="a_blog_content">
    <p>this is test content</p>
</div>
<p class="article_foot"><span>赞(${article.additional.up})</span><span> |
</span><span>阅读(${article.additional.read})</span></p>
```

where things like `$<article.title>` are placeholders to be dynamically assigned with values whenever any backend engine would render the document, say, Spring.

What are your suggestions for the above requirements?

======== Some supplement =========
For the frontend, I choose JQuery;
As to the backend, it is Spring.

Comment: One word `Nodejs`

Comment: Why are the blog_content entries listed in an HTML sheet and not in a database or file storage system somewhere?  Where, exactly, are the blog contents being created?  You can serve up two different web pages via server side includes.  But using a .html page as a data store? ugh.

Comment: use templatesjs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/templatesjs)

Comment: *"backend engine would render the document"* - If the blog article content is being rendered server-side then on the client side that would just be very straightforward Ajax code, e.g., jQuery's `.load()` method.

Comment: for frontend stack I sugest to use `vuejs` files `index` and `blog` are templates that dinamicaly fill.. and for backend use either `node`, `php`, `python` etc, what ever you like

Comment: @zipzit  Well, currently, blog_content are static html documents with placeholders. They are pre-created and located in the web server. I don't think I am using it as data storage anyway.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried using .load, but it only load once. But actually I want several blog_content to be appended into a <div>.

Comment: What exactly is the goal here?  Get back to basics?  I'm thinking you write a REST server to serve up blog content, and use jQuery to make ajax requests to that server to obtain the data in JSON format.  And yeah, that REST server uses string functions to grab the data from blog_content.html files (we'll just pretend that is your data store...)  Is this a homework assignment, or a business issue?

Comment: Instead of telling you not to do this I'll tell you how to do it. You can request the HTML file from the webserver using an HTTP request in JS. I recommend the axios library, but if you don't want that you can use fetch API or XMLHttpRequest (look them up on MDN) Use a GET request for the file. the body of the response will be a string which is all of the HTML of that file. you can either parse it to remove anything you don't want, or just insert it raw. I suggest using a dedicated <div> element where you set the .innerHTML of your element to insert the contents.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that you want to aggregate several html files. well then it comes down to your server design doesn't it? you can create a route on your server that packs them into a JSON array or you can make separate requests and manage them on the frontend.

Comment: Actually JQuery can do HTTP requests too. So what is it you're missing? You can request the files and insert the contents into an element with what you have already.

Comment: hi @zipzit, you can just imagine it as a homework because I am totally new to web development :(      What I want exactly is just serving up blog content. But I feel trouble to dynamically arrange the blogs at frontend side. Because the number and content of blogs are dynamic, and especially, the number. i guess i should put each of the blog in its own <div>, but I am not sure how to dynamically generate the <div>s and also fill them with blog content.

Comment: hi @ChrisRollins, conceptually, I know that I could fill the element I have already with the content I obtained from the server. But, I think the problem is that the number of this *element* is uncertain, which is related to the number of blogs I have in the server. You could refer to my last post replying zizit.

Comment: Can I store the blog content (in html format) in database and retrieve them from the client side? Once I have data at the client side, I will be able to arrange them as I wish, is that right?

Comment: I see. Generating a new div is pretty simple. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
Then you can put the content of a blog into that div, and finally append the div to a main div or something using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild
There is also a "JQuery way" you'll have to look it up, I haven't used it in a while. :)
Also are you having trouble determining how many blogs the server is sending? You could send it as a JSON array and serialize it into a javascript array on the frontend, then you know how many blogs you have.

Answer (score 1):

Now look back at the question, I found it a silly one :).
As you guys said, I setup a rest server which serves the blog content. At the client side, it sends request to the server for the contents. With the contents obtained from the server, JavaScripts then assembles the contents into readable elements. All things go clear now. Thank you guys very much for the help.

Comment: Much better. I think learning the task with the REST server will help you in the future.